# Control styling attribute of component via props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

Having following code:

```
export type BreadcrumbItemProps = {
  isCurrent?: boolean;
};

const isCurrent = (props: { isCurrent?: boolean }) => props.isCurrent ? 'normal' : 'bold';

export const Item = styled.span<BreadcrumbItemProps>`
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: default;
  font-weight: ${ props => isCurrent(isCurrent)};
`;
```

Depending on `isCurrent` props I want to control font, either normal or bold, trying to do it I got following error:

> const isCurrent: (props: {
>       isCurrent?: boolean | undefined; }) => "normal" | "bold" Type '(props: { isCurrent?: boolean | undefined; }) => "normal" | "bold"'
>   has no properties in common with type '{ isCurrent?: boolean |
>   undefined; }'.ts(2559)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it should be:

`font-weight: ${ props => isCurrent(props)};`

instead of

`font-weight: ${ props => isCurrent(isCurrent)};`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a function, you should just be able to do the logic inline like so:

```
export type BreadcrumbItemProps = {
  isCurrent?: boolean;
};

export const Item = styled.span<BreadcrumbItemProps>`
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: default;
    font-weight: ${ props.isCurrent ? 'normal' : 'bold'};
`;
```